# What last Active minutes on Gmail account

Tags: gmail

[image]
[image]

I don't understand what this last minutes on Google security. Does that minutes of Gmail mean last use of Gmail? Does that mean I use my Gmail or it only syncing my account?

Answer (score 1):

It means that 28 minutes ago there was an exchange of data between the device/computer and gmail servers. It could have been sending email, receiving email, refreshing, checking the settings, archiving, modifying the labels attached to a message....